# running method from different class in threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a problem with running parallel one class method from another one. Here is my code:

```
class A
{
private:
    std::vector<int> m_vec;
    int id;
public:
    A(){};
    A(int _id):id(_id){};
    ~A(){};

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "id=" << id << "   size=" << m_vec.size() << std::endl;
    }

    void load_vec()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            m_vec.push_back(i);
        }
    }

};


class B
{
private:
    std::vector<A> m_a;
public:
    B()
    {
        m_a.push_back(A(0));
        m_a.push_back(A(1));
    }
    ~B(){};

    void func(int id)
    {
        m_a.at(id).load_vec();
    }

    void run()
    {

        std::thread t_0(&B::func, this, 0);
        std::thread t_1(&B::func, this, 1);
        t_0.join();
        t_1.join();
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (std::vector<A>::iterator itr = m_a.begin(); itr != m_a.end(); itr++ )
        {
            itr->print();
        }
    }

};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{


    A a_0(0), a_1(1);

    clock_t time = clock();
    a_0.load_vec();
    a_1.load_vec();

    time = clock() - time;

    std::cout << "finish in: " << ((float)time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<< std::endl;

    B b;

    time = clock();

    b.run();
    std::cout << "finish in: " << ((float)time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<< std::endl;

    b.print();

    return 0;
}
```

and this is result:

```
finish in: 8.20428
finish in: 8.21259
id=0   size=100000000
id=1   size=100000000
```

My problem is, that time to finish task by 2 threads is bigger, then running method 2 times in 1 thread. Can anyone help me please? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clock` function returns CPU time, not real time.  You use a similar amount of CPU time with one thread or two, but two threads should use half as much real time.